# Is there a way to loop for each element that is the same as in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm pretty new to Javascript, so forgive me if I make any obvious mistakes.

Essentially, I have two arrays and I want to loop for each element that is also in the second array. So far I have this:

```
if(obtainedCards.some( sp => Boosters.SP.includes(sp)))
{
    obtainedCards.forEach(potential => Boosters.SP.includes(potential))
    {
        // CHANGE THIS BACK TO 0, 100 AFTER TESTING
        this.chance = CardsBetween(76, 100);

        console.log(this.chance);
        if(this.chance >= 76)
        {
            this.noOfSPs += 1;
            console.log("Test: " + this.chance);
        }
    };

    console.log("Chance is: " + this.chance);
    console.log("No of SPs is: " + this.noOfSPs);

   //return chance, 
   return noOfSPs;
}
```

The first `if` statement works as intended, but the `forEach` doesn't. It will only execute once, even though I know there are multiple elements that are in both arrays.

Comment: What are the two arrays you have?

Comment: I think is not looping at all, did you see the console for any errors? that code has a lot of syntax errors.

Comment: The first array is the one I want to compare against (its 50 elements long so I can't show it), and the second array has elements pushed to it from a third array. There are also no errors in the console, the code runs with no errors, it just doesn't loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first filter out all the elements in the first array, which don't exist in the second array.
And then the result of the filter, is the array that you wish to map.

```
const array_1 = [1, 2, 3];
const array_2 = [4, 5, 2];

const getArrayWithSameElements = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));
}

getArrayWithSameElements(array_1, array_2).map(item => console.log(item)) // This will loop through every item in array 1, which is present in array 2
```